# Sum group of rows based on value in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL and I have the below tables

[image: Table Data]

that I need to select and get the desired result below. 
[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Please avoid images: what we actually need are re-usable formatted text. Also post what you have tried yet. Stackoverflow is here to help you with specific issues, not to make your homeworks for you :)

Comment: seems like home work.. Show us your attempt and let us know where you stuck to get this done. And also posting images would not get help quickly, as people need to write all structure for you.

Comment: This is a simple select statement with a group by to sum by groups. The only difficult part is to get the columns Dr and Cr depending on the TransactionTypeId, you can calculate them using a CASE construction : case when TransactionTypeId = 1 then Amount else 0 end as Dr

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to abide by the advice given by @B3S for future question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a query like below.

```
select  
    [Account Group] =AG.Name,
    [Ledger Name]   =AL.Name,
    DR  =SUM(CASE WHEN TT.Name='DR' THEN Amount ELSE NULL END),-- case based SUM expression
    CR  =SUM(CASE WHEN TT.Name='CR' THEN Amount ELSE NULL END)
from Account_Group AG
join Account_ledgers AL -- NOTE  we have used INNER JOIN throughout
    on AG.Id=AL.AccountGroupId
join Transactions  T
    on T.AccountLedgerId=AL.Id
join Transaction_Type TT
    on TT.Id= T.TransactionTypeId
group by AG.Name,AL.Name -- Group by contains all the things we need in SELECT list
```